# Htaccess - redirect 'files' with no file extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect only php files and files with no file extension like these:

```
http://www.test.com/test.php
http://www.test.com/TEST
```

I have this htaccess script, which redirects php files to target.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^\.]+\.php$ /target.php [L,NC]
```

Now I need to add files with no extension to this redirect.

Thanks for help!

Comment: @llyssis isnt the issue here that files with no extension could be directories on the webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rules should do the job.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^\.]+\.php$ /target.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^\.]*[^/\.]$ /target.php [L,NC]
```

The redirect will work for `http://www.test.com/TEST` as long as you do not have folder or file named `TEST` in your site.